# Allow scrolling in fullPage section only after section below fades in

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I use a delay.fadeIn for all of my sections, so they appear at different times. For example the second section has a delay(20000).fadeIn() function that makes it appear 20 seconds after page load - and the rest of my sections appear like that at different times.

My problem is that, if you scroll to a section before it has faded in, fullPage takes you back to the first section. I'm looking to prevent scrolling down until a new section is has faded in.

From [fullPage's documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/), I think I could use setAllowScrolling (see below) - but need to make sure you the user will still be able to navigate up and down, but just not past the last available section.

> setAllowScrolling(boolean)
>
> Adds or remove the possiblity of scrolling through sections by using
>   the mouse wheel/trackpad or touch gestures (which is active by
>   default).
>
> $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);

Note I have both 'loopBottom': false and 'loopTop': false,

Hope this makes sense, and appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the `fp-section` class added by the plugin to all your sections after it has been initialized.

If you remove it from some sections, those sections won't exist for the plugin. It will ignore them and you won't be able to scroll to them.

Just add the class `fp-section` dynamically after you finish your fadeIn.